# Помогите автоматизировать работу с таблицей excel

Tags: excel

Имеется таблица такого плана:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В колонке `op_time` иногда стоит 1. В колонке `%USTEC` указана формула, которая должна реагировать на присутствие или отсутствие единицы в колонке `op_time` следующим образом:

1. если в предыдущей строке колонки `op_time` указана единица, то в колонке `%USTEC` должна вычисляться разность между текущим значением `<OPEN> USTEC` (в данном случае - 12946.1) и значением `<OPEN> USTEC` в той строке, в которой указана единица (12946), причем ссылка на последнее значение абсолютная, т.е. при растягивании формулы вниз не изменяется. В данном случае, правда, формула сложнее, т.к. высчитываются процент роста, а не простая разность, но это не принципиально.
2. если в предыдущей строке колонки `op_time` не указана единица, то формула из предыдущей строки колонки  `%USTEC` должна "растягиваться" вниз на эту ячейку.

В общем, не знаю, понятно ли я объясняю, но в конечном счете мне нужно всякий раз вычислять % роста актива относительно его цены в определенный момент времени, например, насколько % актив вырос в цене относительно его значения в 16:00:00. Но это время может меняться, и для этого существует 1 в столбце `op_time`, т.е. если 1 указана в строке с временем 16:00:00, то отсчет % роста актива осуществляется с этого времени, если в строке с временем 10:00:00, то отсчет % роста начинается с этого времени.

В таблице содержатся данные за 550 дней, т.е. будет 550 единиц в графе op_time.

Comment: Правильно ли: найти разность значений из текущей строки и из последней строки, в которой есть единица? Не о формулах надо рассказывать, а о задаче.

Comment: Да, Вы все верно поняли. Извините, выражаюсь, как могу, не специалист. Единственное, возможно это лучше сделать через макрос, потому что сам файл итак очень большой, боюсь, на моем железе в итоге все это может повиснуть. Я в макросы не вникала, но попробую разобраться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В ячейку *I2* и протянуть вниз:

```
=E2-ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ПРОСМОТР(1;$G$1:G1;$E$1:E1);)
```

*ЕСЛИОШИБКА* только для первых строк, выше которых нет единицы. В строках ниже можно исключить функцию:

```
=E2-ПРОСМОТР(1;$G$1:G1;$E$1:E1)
```

Comment: попробовала Ваш вариант, и что-то он первые два раза считает правильно, а потом нет. Правда, я посмотрела справку по функции, там в тексте для 365 версии рекомендуют функцию ПРОСМОТРX. Я ей воспользовалась и у меня все получилось. Файл https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhiEKtfBh5MPi-QQA8FRKFnbfdzERg?e=faiNZz мой вариант deltaX Ваш delta